# why apexchart not being rendered correctly in vue(spa) when chart type changes?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, apexcharts

I have a v-tab items bar with 3 type of graphs, all have to show data from a single variable. variable is being updated upon selecting an option from v-select.
it renders correctly 1st time but then upon changing the option all data renders correctly in all the charts except for the xaxis categories. xaxis values do not appear along the ticks. but are visible in tool tip view.
On resizing the window, the data appears again, cant forcefully render the chart upon change.
need some help.

```
    <v-tabs
                      center-active
                      v-model="ctab"
                      color="#a24187"
                      slider-color="#a24187"
                    >
                      <v-tab >
                        <v-icon color="#2E93fA">mdi-poll</v-icon> Bar</v-tab
                      >
                      <v-tab >
                        <v-icon color="#2E93fA">mdi-chart-timeline-variant</v-icon>Line
                      </v-tab>
                      <v-tab >
                        <v-icon color="#2E93fA">mdi-scatter-plot</v-icon> Scatter</v-tab
                      >
                    </v-tabs>
                    <v-tabs-items v-model="ctab" class="px-2">
                      <v-tab-item>

                        <apexchart
                          ref="chart"
                          width="700"
                          height="260"
                          type="bar"
                          :options="chartoptions"
                          :series="sr"
                        ></apexchart>
                      </v-tab-item>

                      <v-tab-item>
                        <apexchart
                          ref="chart"
                          width="700"
                          height="260"
                          type="line"
                          :options="chartoptions"
                          :series="sr"
                        ></apexchart>
                      </v-tab-item>

                      <v-tab-item>
                        <apexchart
                          ref="chart"
                          width="700"
                          height="260"
                          type="scatter"
                          :options="chartoptions"
                          :series="sr"
                        ></apexchart>
                      </v-tab-item>
                    </v-tabs-items>
```

**Variables and properties being used**

```
 sr: [
      {
        name: "",
        data: [],
      },
    ],
    chartoptions: {
      chart: {
        id: "UNChart",
      },

      xaxis: {
        categories: [],
        axisBorder: {
          show: true,
          color: "#a24187",
          height: 1,
          width: "100%",
          offsetX: 0,
          offsetY: 0,
        },
        axisTicks: {
          show: true,
          borderType: "solid",
          color: "#a24187",
          height: 6,
          offsetX: 0,
          offsetY: 0,
        },
      },
      yaxis: {
        axisBorder: {
          show: true,
          color: "#a24187",
          offsetX: 0,
          offsetY: 0,
        },
        axisTicks: {
          show: true,
          borderType: "solid",
          color: "#a24187",
          width: 6,
          offsetX: 0,
          offsetY: 0,
        },
      },
      title: {
        text: undefined,
        align: "left",
        margin: 10,
        offsetX: 0,
        offsetY: 0,
        floating: false,
        style: {
          fontSize: "14px",
          fontWeight: "bold",
          fontFamily: undefined,
          color: "#263238",
        },
      },
    },
```

**Method being used to get data**

```
showchart() {
      this.tempData = [];
      this.tempCategory = [];
      this.sr[0].data = [];
      this.sr[0].name = "";
      this.chartoptions.xaxis.categories = [];
      for (let index = 0; index < this.newdata.length; index++) {
        if (this.criteria === this.newdata[index].specific_title) {
          this.tempData.push(this.newdata[index].current_value);
          this.tempCategory.push(this.newdata[index].specific_name);
        }
      }
      // ApexCharts.exec(
      //   "UNChart",
      //   "updateOptions",
      //   {
      //     xaxis: {
      //       categories: this.tempCategory,
      //     },
      //   },
      //   false,
      //   true
      // );

      // ApexCharts.exec(
      //   "UNChart",
      //   "updateSeries",
      //   [
      //     {
      //       data: this.tempData,
      //       name: this.criteria,
      //     },
      //   ],
      //   true
      // );

      this.sr = [
        {
          name: this.criteria,
          data: this.tempData,
        },
      ];
      this.chartoptions = {
        ...this.chartoptions,
        ...{
          xaxis: { categories: this.tempCategory },
          title: { text: this.filter.theme.name },
        },
      };

      // this.$refs.chart.updateOptions({ xaxis: { categories: this.tempCategory } });
    },
```

1
[image: FIRST VIEW]

2
[image: OPTION SELECTED FIRST TIME]

3
[image: cORRECTLY WORKING DUE TO FIRST SELECTION]

4
[image: cHANGING OPTION]

5
[image]